# post a comment to facebook from app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

So the goal here is to ask a user to post something to their wall with a specific hashtag , when they do this I would like to post a comment to this post from our app with something like "Thank you for your post, come back to http://www.mysite.com for the next step".  So far I successfully query the user's posts , and I am successfully finding the post with the specific hashtag.  When I find the post I also get the `post_id` of the post.

So after reading everything I could find from the docs , I am able to post a comment from the user if I do something like this with graph api. (This is using Facebook c# sdk)

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient();
client.Post("832586561_10152125349566562/comments", new
{
    message = "test message from app"
});
```

now with this code I am using the user's access_token, and it works fine , but on Facebook it will show up as the user commenting on their own post.  That is not what we want , we want the comment to appear to be coming from  our app.  So I tried using the app access token instead of the user's access_token, and when I try i get an error for not enough permission.  I do not even know if this is possible to be done with the app access token.  I tried adding all the extended permissions that I could find that had anything to do with publiching and I still get the error for not enough permission , right now I ask for these extended permissions on login.

```
{ scope: 'email,publish_stream,email,rsvp_event,read_stream,user_likes,user_birthday,publish_actions,manage_pages' });
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can post a comment to a specific post and have that comment comming from the app?

Comment: You want to impersonate your app via someone else's account? That doesn't sound possible. Doesn't the permission say "Post on behalf of me".. not, "Post as someone else via my account"? That very statement doesn't really make sense either :/

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - no I want to post to someones wall , this user will have already granted any necessary permissions.  I would like the post to come from my app.  I don't see why this would be a problem, I am authorized to make api calls from my app.

Comment: Ohhh, I thought you wanted to post a comment - as your app - to any of the user's available posts. Apologies for the misunderstanding.